# Flask: ValueError: variable name 'X' used twice.

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to server thumbnail images from disk by template name, but following code produce error: `ValueError: variable name 'site_hash' used twice`, so how to overcome this problem?

```
@app.route('/site/<site_hash>/<site_hash>_thumb.png')
def serve_img(site_hash):

    print('site_hash', site_hash)

    with open(os.path.join('./sites', site_hash, site_hash + '_thumb.png'), 'r') as f:
        txt = f.read()
        return txt
```

Comment: Use two different variable names in your route and verify that they're equal inside your function?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use same variable in `@app.route` twice. Just rename it. Smth like this

```
@app.route('/site/<site_hash>/<site_hash_second>_thumb.png')
def serve_img(site_hash, site_hash_second):
```

But it's still unclear what `site_hash` means, you better give your url parameters reasonable names.